# Using arrays in django views.py code - is it a good habit?

Tags: python, django

I have couple of functions which captures ajax requests. I get the data from the request and put into the array. Then I loopthru this array in another function for instance to pass the data to context. This solution basically works, but is it a good way of doing things ? Appreciate for any feedback.

piece of code:

```
user_choices = []
@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def make_order(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        for order in data["array"]:
            user_choices.append(order)
        return HttpResponse(200)
    else:
        return redirect(request, 'home')

movie = 0
seats = []
@login_required
def confirmation(request):
    if len(user_choices) > 0:
        movie = Movies.objects.get(pk=int(user_choices[0]["id"]))
        for seat in user_choices:
            seats.append(seat["row"]+":"+seat["seat"])
        context = {
            "movie":movie.title,
            "seats":seats
        }

        return render(request, "main_templates/confirmation.html", context)
    else:
        return redirect("home")
```

Comment: No, please do *not* use global state.

Answer (score 4):

> I have couple of functions which captures ajax requests. I get the data from the request and put into the array. Then I loopthru this array in another function for instance to pass the data to context. This solution basically works, but is it a good way of doing things?

**No**, you introduce an anti-pattern called [*global state* [se]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148108/166310). Global state is a serious anti-pattern because it makes a program *unpredictable*. Depending on previous requests, the list can already contain data. Normally a GET request should have *no* side-effects. By altering lists, that is no longer the case.

Furthermore in this specific case, it means that if one user queries for data, and then another user makes a request for data, the data of the first user "leaks" to the second user.

But nevertheless, even if you manage to make it more safe, a global state introduces a lot of difficulties. These are discussed in the [software engineering post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148108/166310). While you can of course each time aim to manually fix these issues, it will result in a lot of work and bugs, and therefore more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: I thought so it wasn;t a good way. Should i stick to GET, POST requests then ?

Comment: @husa: AJAX requests are also GET/POST/... requests. The point is that a GET request is not allowed (by the HTTP standard) to have side effects. So strictly speaking if you make two GET requests, immediately after each other, then the data retrieved should be exactly the same.

Comment: What about using arrays inside the functions ?

Comment: @husa: that is not much of a problem, since at the end of the function, the lists are garbage collected, and thus can no longer influence the next request.

Comment: I see :) Now I have to figure it out how to pass captured ajax data (in views) to the template. Thanks

Comment: Sorry to bother you - request.session["movie_id"] = movie_id what about this way ? I see this one is similar to php sessions, so I believe should be reliable ? :)